# Angular FormArray based custom form control validation problem

Tags: angular, validation

Please check the following problem,

I created a custom component which is a checklist, I used `FormArray` to represent the rows. Each row is a form array item, so a `FormGroup`.

Here is the form defnition of the main(in my case exampleForm)

```
this.exampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  selectionMode: this.formBuilder.control( { value: SelectionMode.SINGLE, disabled: false} ),
  selectNormal: this.formBuilder.control( { value: false, disabled: false } ),
  **checkList**: this.formBuilder.group( [ Validators.required ] )
});
```

The template of the checkList FormGroup is the following,

```
        <app-checklist [checklistItems]="checklistItems"
            #checkListFormArrayControl
            [selectionMode]="selectionMode"
            [selectNormal]="selectNormal"
            [required]="true"
            **formGroupName="checkList"**
            (onClick)="onClick($event)"
            >
            <span *ngIf="exampleForm?.get('checkList')?.dirty && exampleForm?.get('checkList')?.errors?.invalidForm" class="show-invalid-feedback">
                {{ exampleForm?.get('checkList')?.errors?.invalidForm.message }}
            </span>
        </app-checklist>
```

Where the `checkList: this.formBuilder.group( [ Validators.required ] )` is a custom form control which implemented in a separated component.

The app-checklist component is based of a reactive form see below,

```
  createInternalForm() {
    this.mainForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      checkListFormArray: this.formBuilder.array( [], [ ChecklistValidators.oneItemCheckRequiredValidator ] )
    });
  }
```

**The problem is, with the custom component 'app-checklist' don't roll up the validation status to the parent form.**

Currently I have no idea to that. **In the app-checklist component the validation status is correct.** (can see on the console log, check the live example url below) But **the main form (exampleForm) absolutely not follow the validation status of the app-checklis component** which defined as checkList form group in the main form.

[Here is](https://lkovari.github.io/KLHome/#/angular-page/angular-page-content11) the live example

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link is to a localhost URL. Could you please upload the example to Stackblitz or similar so we can see it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed it. So I created a FormArray based Checklist component. The component is forks fine except for it not rolling up the validation result to the parent form. Maybe in the component I shouldn't use a form, maybe just a FormArray instead of it, I don't know.

Comment: Added detailed information

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with the following code in the child component:

```
// get the parent form (FormGroup)
this.parentForm = this.formGroupDirective.control as FormGroup;
// capture the elementRef to get formGroupName attribute to replace the formgGroup which in used by the component (in our case the checkList)
let formGroupName = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('formGroupName');
// replace the build checkList on the parent form with the checkListFormArray which built in this component
this.parentForm.setControl(formGroupName, this.mainForm.controls.checkListFormArray);
```

The related template part on the parent form:

```
        <app-checklist [checklistItems]="checklistItems"
            #checkListGroup
            #checkListRef
            [elementRef]="checkListReference"
            [selectionMode]="selectionMode"
            [selectNormal]="selectNormal"
            [required]="true"
            formGroupName="checkList"
            (onClick)="onClick($event)"
            >
        </app-checklist>
```

We can observe the elementRef is passed, into the child component would not want to hardcode the control name, see below the ViewChild on the .ts of the parent form.

```
  // pass the element ref into the component
  @ViewChild('checkListRef', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) checkListReference: ElementRef;
```